# how to check and uncheck all checkboxes on button click using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 5 checkboxes in my webform.

i have button1 whose text is select all ....

i want when button1 text is select all then i clcik on button then all the checkboxes will be checked and button1 text will be unselect all .... if the button text is unselect all then all the checkboxes will be unchecked ...

how to do this using vb.net ?

Comment: You know, a (small) fragment of the .aspx would make answering a lot easier.

Comment: Are the Checkboxes all on a Panel?

Comment: ya ... i have the question mentioned above ... only

Comment: Ya all the checkboxes are inside panel 1 and panel1 is inside updatepanel and all the controsl are in usercontrol

Comment: @Sumit: You can Edit your question and add information.

Comment: The question is mentioned above. .. i wanna write the code for this in vb.net ...i dont have any idea how to do this .. i have checkboxes inside panel1 and panel1 inside update panel ..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should get it

ASPX:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Check All" />
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="apple" Value="apple" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="banana" Value="banana" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="grapes" Value="grapes" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="kiwi" Value="kiwi" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="orange" Value="orange" />
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim toggle As Boolean = True
    If Button1.Text = "Check All" Then
        Button1.Text = "Uncheck All"
    Else
        Button1.Text = "Check All"
        toggle = False
    End If

    For Each li As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        li.Selected = toggle
    Next
End Sub
```

**Alternatively** you could do this easily client side jquery

something like

```
$('#Button1').click(function() {
    var toggle = true;
    if ($(this).val() === "Check All") {
        $(this).val("Uncheck All");
    } else {
        $(this).val("Check All");
        toggle = false;
    }
    $('.myCheckBoxes :checkbox').attr("checked", toggle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using jQuery for this.  You would need something like the following in your ASPX file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".select-all-button").click(function() {
            var any = ($(".cb > input:checked").length > 0);
            $(".cb > input").attr("checked", !any);
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Button ID="SelectAllButton" Text="Select All" CssClass="select-all-button" runat="server"/><br/><br/>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" CssClass="cb" Text="CheckBox 1" runat="Server" /><br/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" CssClass="cb" Text="CheckBox 2" runat="Server" /><br/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" CssClass="cb" Text="CheckBox 3" runat="Server" /><br/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" CssClass="cb" Text="CheckBox 4" runat="Server" /><br/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" CssClass="cb" Text="CheckBox 5" runat="Server" /><br/>
```

Comment: jQuery inside an UpdatePanel??